# Android sdk based example for Parrot bebop drone

Tags: android, ar.drone

I need to find a sample program that uses android sdk for parrot bebop drone. I did my research but couldn't find any yet.

Answer (score 2):

As you named the drone Bebop, I assume you want samples of the ARDroneSDK3.

Here is where you can download the SDK : [ARDroneSDK3](https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3/ARSDKBuildUtils) If you scroll down, you can access the installation documentation : [Installation documentation](https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3/Docs/blob/master/Installation/INSTALL) ; or the samples files : [Samples](https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3/Samples)

All the samples are not on the Bebop drone but they use the same SDK. Look for the other drones samples or OS, that will help you code your own app.